# How to convert JSON into XML in Swift?

Tags: json, xml, swift

I have a `JSON` body that I sending over `HTTP` using POST. Instead of sending `JSON` as payload I would like to convert it to XML and send it over. How can I achieve this in `Swift`?

I am a newbie in `Swift` and hence does not have much idea. I googled around but could not find anything specifically for converting `JSON` to `XML`.

Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine two libraries, use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) to parse JSON and then [AEXML](https://github.com/tadija/AEXML) to convert it into XML. Read the Docs, it's an easy approach.